# How to select Element with certain Class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

so if I want to apply a style to `<Div Class="ScreenShot ">`

Here's what I tried that works in my tests. But, surprisingly, I can't find this documented (in [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), etc.)

```
div.ScreenShot {  display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: What are you asking? Your example works because `div.ScreenShot` searches for `div`s with the class `ScreenShot`. You can also leave out `div` and only write `.ScreenShot`.

Comment: If in doubt, ask MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.ScreenShot` or `div.ScreenShot` as a selector, both work.

But `div.ScreenShot` has a higher specifity, so if there are different rules with both selectors that contain different settings, the settings in `div.ScreenShot` will overwrite those in `.ScreenShot`